# Why is there a numerical difference using an expression directly versus in a closure taking f32?

Tags: rust, floating-point, type-inference

This code:

```
let average = |a: f32, b: f32, c: f32| {
    (a + b + c) / 3.0
};

println!("With function: {}", average(11.0, -22.0, 33.0));
println!("Without function: {}", (11.0 - 22.0 + 33.0) / 3.0);
```

prints this result:

```
With function: 7.3333335
Without function: 7.333333333333333
```

Why are they different?

Answer (score 4):

The discrepancy comes from using different types to evaluate the same mathematical expression. The closure uses `f32`s (as annotated) while the version without it uses `f64`s. The type of numeric literals with decimals [defaults](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/literal-expr.html#floating-point-literal-expressions) to `f64` unless inferred or suffixed otherwise.

So the latter has twice the precision. If the closure were annotated with `f64`s instead, you would get the same result:

```
let average = |a: f64, b: f64, c: f64| {
    (a + b + c) / 3.0
};

println!("With function: {}", average(11.0, -22.0, 33.0));
println!("Without function: {}", (11.0 - 22.0 + 33.0) / 3.0);
```

```
With function: 7.333333333333333
Without function: 7.333333333333333
```